# Does Shapeless 2.0.0 lens work with Lists/collections?

Tags: scala, shapeless

If I have this:

```
case class Foo(
    age: Int,
    name: String,
    bar: List[Bar],
    alive: Boolean
    )
case class Bar(
    hey: String,
    you: String
    )
```

Can I create a lens that can get/set `foo.bar(1).you`?

Comment: Just thinking out loud here: maybe `Foo#bar` could be redefined as a `HList` instead of `List`?

Comment: @ErikAllik: For that to be useful you'd need to add a type parameter for the type of the `HList` to `Foo`, which is likely to be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: not if bar contains the same types of items a the time.

Comment: @ErikAllik: Yes, you'll still need the type if you want to use the `>> _1` lens syntax, which is presumably the goal. You can't do anything with an `HList`.

Comment: I understand that (meant to write "all the time" btw).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not out of the box, and you really need a partial lens to look things up in a list by index responsibly. Scalaz provides what you need, though, and [shapeless-contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/shapeless-contrib) makes interoperability easy:

```
import scalaz.PLens._
import shapeless.lens
import shapeless.contrib.scalaz._

val secondBar = (lens[Foo] >> 'bar).asScalaz.partial.andThen(listNthPLens(1))
```

And then:

```
scala> secondBar.get(fooB)
res0: Option[Bar] = None

scala> secondBar.get(fooA)
res1: Option[Bar] = Some(Bar(foo,bar))

scala> secondBar.set(fooA, Bar("bar", "foo"))
res2: Option[Foo] = Some(Foo(1,,List(Bar(,), Bar(bar,foo)),false))

scala> secondBar.set(fooB, Bar("bar", "foo"))
res3: Option[Foo] = None
```

If you don't mind living dangerously, you could also write your own Shapeless lens for looking up locations in a list (with a type like `Lens[List[A], A]`), but that would be giving up a lot of the value of both Shapeless and lenses.